# Appcelerator ti.paint module won't load image on android

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

I have an error with the ti.paint module on android.
Whenever I try to set an image, my application crashes (works fine on iOS)
I've try several codes :

```
var paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    top:0, right:0, bottom:80, left:0,
    image : "images/doge.png",
    eraseMode : true,
    strokeWidth : 70
});
```

and

```
image : "/images/doge.png"
```

also

```
image = "http://dogr.io/doge.png"
```

and finally

```
var dogeFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'images/doge.png');
var paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    top:0, right:0, bottom:80, left:0,
    image : dogeFile.nativePath,
    eraseMode : true,
    strokeWidth : 70
});
```

But the application crash each time on Android (works fine on iOS).

I've also tried with jpeg images, and even with a NULL value.

Here is the error message I'm getting in the console

```
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [0,205] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wow.much.scratch/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException; Titanium 3.2.3,2014/04/22 10:17,b958a70
[ERROR] TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wow.much.scratch/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR] TiApplication: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.modules.titanium.paint.UIPaintView$PaintView.setImage(UIPaintView.java:224)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.modules.titanium.paint.UIPaintView.<init>(UIPaintView.java:42)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.modules.titanium.paint.PaintViewProxy.createView(PaintViewProxy.java:30)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:463)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:449)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:487)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:471)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:449)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleAdd(TiViewProxy.java:566)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.add(TiViewProxy.java:544)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.WindowProxy.windowCreated(WindowProxy.java:303)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivityWindows.windowCreated(TiActivityWindows.java:32)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.windowCreated(TiBaseActivity.java:452)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:528)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:18)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  ... 11 more
```

I'm running Titanium SDK 3.2.3.GA.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a work-around can you put an image in a view behind the paint module and paint over the top of it.  You can then capture the entire view if you needed to save that image.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the image loaded in the module so I can erase it, to create some kind of scratch card

Answer (score 0):

I currently work on ti.paint and I met the same problem with Android.
the management view for Android is different from that of Titanium, then this created the problem...
The idea is to use a main thread.

Here the change in PaintViewProxy.java module :

```
@Kroll.setProperty
@Kroll.method
public void setImage(String imagePath) {
    final String imgPath = imagePath;
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            paintView.setImage(imgPath);
        }
    });
}
```

Recompile it and it should work, it works for me.
I hope you have help ...